# Wikipage with several dataview webparts (master-detail)

Tags: list-view, connected-web-parts, master-detail

I need to create a page with several connected dataview webparts.
Assume we do have the following lists

1. Project
2. Subproject (has a lookup column to Project)
3. Tasks (has a lookup column to Subproject)

On my page I have placed all 3 ListView webparts and setup the connections.

1. Project --> Subproject
2. Subproject --> Tasks

Everything works just fine except one thing.

The Task list is not "filtering" correctly. When I select a project and then a subproject which has task I do see only the tasks blonging to this subproject...thats fine. But when I then select a different project the task list still shows the tasks of the subproject I selected before. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Tasks list only detects events from the Subproject list, so it doesn't know when there's a change in the Project list. You can add a second filter connection to the Tasks web part from the Project web part. When you change Projects, the Tasks will be empty until someone selects a Subproject.

If that's not an acceptable solution, you may be able to get different behavior by building dataviews with custom filters in SharePoint Designer, but I've never tried it.

Comment: Hi. Not sure what you mean by "add a second filter connection". I am not allowed to use Sharepoint Designer. :-(

Comment: I didn't realize you were just using column filters, rather than filter web parts. You're not doing anything wrong. The filter on Projects remains until you clear the filter manually. If there are no tasks related to that Project, then there will be no tasks displayed as long as that project is selected.